# Как получить JSON данные с сервера в Android?

Tags: java, android, json, веб-сервер, httpurlconnection

Надо получить одну переменную int с сервера. Не получается, эмулятор вылетает, никакую ошибку не выдаёт. Код вот такой:

```
private class DownloadDataTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        java.net.URL url =` null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            url = new URL(strings[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream =  urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                result.append(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            return  result.toString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
            poluchennyedannye = jsonObject.getInt("data");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ВСЕ ПЛОХО!!!!! ВЫРУБАЙ ЭТОТ КОД, НИЧЕ НЕ РАБОТАЕТ!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Код выглядит что написан лет 10 назад. Может пришло время переписать? Есть куча библиотек в помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Для начала в папке res/xml нужно создать файл: network_security_config.xml со следующим содержимым:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <network-security-config>
       <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"/>
   </network-security-config>
   ```
2. В файле AndroidManifest.xml добавить следующие строки:

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

   <application
       android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
       android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
   ```
3. Теперь всё будет работать:

   ```
   package com.example.android;

   import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

   import android.os.AsyncTask;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.util.Log;
   import android.widget.Toast;

   import org.json.JSONException;
   import org.json.JSONObject;

   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.InputStreamReader;
   import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
   import java.net.URL;

   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            MyTask myTask = new MyTask();
            myTask.execute();
        }

        private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Подключение к API", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                try {

                    URL url = new URL("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1");

                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                    httpURLConnection.connect();

                    if(httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                        throw new Exception(httpURLConnection.getResponseMessage())
                    }

                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
                    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        builder.append(line);
                    }

                    bufferedReader.close();
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
                super.onPostExecute(unused);

                try {

                    JSONObject buffer = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
                    Log.d("Тайтл", buffer.getString("title"));

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
   }
   ```

Comment: Спасибо большое.